# Prevent some sheet actions by users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have given "Edit" rights to some users. I am the owner.

I prevent Add or Delete or hide or resize Column (by user) by protecting Row1 (only editable by owner).

But, I have seen some dummy sheets getting added by the user. I can delete these sheets by script which runs once a day. Is there a better way to prevent a user from adding a sheet?

If a user (who is an editor) deletes a sheet, the system will collapse. How to prevent an editor from deleting a sheet? This is very important for me.

Some users press the "Add 1000 rows" button at the bottom and add unnecessary rows. Is there a way to prevent it? Now, I have made an option in the menu which deletes the empty rows.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a web app which provides the editing capability but doesn’t give access to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can't prevent a user with edit access from creating new Sheets or rows, but you can run an `onChange()` trigger which deletes them as soon as they're created.*

#### More Information:

The [`onChange()` trigger of Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) is an installable trigger which runs when a change to the structure of a Sheet is made.

The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for the chenged event contains information about the type of change - specifically `INSERT_GRID` and `INSERT_ROW` - these refer to a Sheet structure change of a new Sheet added and a new row or range of rows inserted.

From here you can then handle the immediate removal of them.

#### Code:

```js
function onChange(e) {
  
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_GRID") {
    // list your sheet names in here:
    var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    
    if (sheets.length != sheetNames.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        if (sheetNames.includes(sheets[i].getName())) {
          continue;
        }
        else {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(sheets[i])
        }
      }          
    }
  } 
  
  else if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    // define how many rows your sheet has here:
    var noOfRows = 200;    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    
    
    sheet.getRange((noOfRows + 1) + ':' + (noOfRows + 1)).activate();
    
    var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
    
    sheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    
    currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
    sheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(sheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), sheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  }
}
```

#### Setting up the Trigger:

Save the script with the save icon, press the run button (►), and confirm the authentication of running the script.

From here, following the Edit > Current project's triggers menu item, you will have a new page open in the G Suite Developer Hub. Click the + Add Trigger button in the bottom right and set up the trigger settings as follows:

- Choose which function to run: `onChange`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `From spreadsheet`
- Select event type: `On change`

And press save.

#### Deleted Sheets:

This is the tricky part; unfortunately, there is no way of recovering deleted sheets by catching them with an `onChange()`.

If this is a huge importance, however, the best thing I can recommend is taking a look at [file revisions of Drive files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308971?hl=en) and the Drive API's file [`revisions: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) and [`revisions: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get) methods, and do some integration of this on `e.changeType == REMOVE_GRID`, but in reality you should just try and back the sheet up as often as you can so that if important structure is lost it can be easily recovered.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Google Sheets `onchange()` event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
- [Check or revert to earlier file versions - G Suite Learning Center](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308971?hl=en)
- [`Revisions: list` | Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- [`Revisions: get` | Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to easily "protect" your spreadsheet in this way. However, you can add an `onChange` trigger to your spreadsheet (read more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)) which will run a function whenever somebody changes the format or structure of your spreadsheet. From the script editor, click `edit` > `current project's triggers` which will open a new window. There you can add a new trigger (select a function to execute and the spreadsheet event `onChange`). Here's the function that you could link to the trigger:

```
function onChange(e) {
  /* e is the event object, see documentation */
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    /* delete unneeded empty rows at the end */
    removeEmptyRows();
  } else if (e.changeType == "INSERT_GRID") {
    /* delete unwanted sheets */
    removeExtraSheets();
  }
}
```

As for preventing users from deleting a sheet, it seems like there is no option to do that. You can catch the deletion of a sheet in the `onChange` function, the `changeType` will be `"REMOVE_GRID"` but the event object will not allow you to access the deleted data.

So, if you have important data in the sheets (and don't trust the editors to *not* delete the sheets), you should probably backup your data regularly (using a time-based trigger and a second backup spreadsheet that only you can access).